# Can't set an variable in jquery getjson function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to set an variable in the function after i send an ajax request.
What is the reason why the function alert outside the getjson function undefined and inside the good value? Is there some solution?

```
function gettextlabel(txtvar){ 
    var v = '';
    $.getJSON('http://192.168.0.92/visuals/support/text_handler.php?txtvar=' + txtvar , function(data) {
        v = data;
        alert(v);
    });
    alert(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because by default jQuery send ajax request asynchronously.

You can set the option `async` to false to force it work synchronously, like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://192.168.0.92/visuals/support/text_handler.php?txtvar=' + txtvar,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {  v = data; alert(v); },
    async: false
});
```

Comment: Note: `async: false` will lock up the browser until the AJAX call is done.  I suggest **not** using it unless you *really* need to.  You should add all stuff related to this JSON into the callback.

Comment: @Rocket Yep, that's right :), add the related code to the callback is the most normal solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function gettextlabel(txtvar){ 
    var v = '';

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.0.92/visuals/support/text_handler.php',
        data: 'txtvar=' + txtvar,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            v = data;
            alert(v);
        }
    });

    alert(v);
}
```

Comment: Note: `async: false` will lock up the browser until the AJAX call is done.  I suggest **not** using it unless you *really* need to.  You should add all stuff related to this JSON into the callback.